# Script not working when animation is enabled

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, blender

I am testing to make a cube move with a script. Also have a simple Roll animation for the cube which is supposed to activate whenever I move the cube.

But the cube doesn't move when the animation is 'checked' as active under the inspector tab. The cube only moves if I disable animation thus not even able to see if the animation works properly when I move the cube. The cube is imported from Blender to Unity. Please advice what I am doing wrong.

The script is as follows. It is a very simple and small test file thus I have attached my Unity and Blender files too at Dropbox for reference if that helps. Thank you.

Link to Unity Project:

https://www.dropbox.com/sh/cvpjf26i31o1ell/AABmLMqYV4tPiG7qruph2D4Ra?dl=0

Link to Blender model and animation:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/deowh3yk5wpse1u/box.blend?dl=0

Movement script for cube:

```
public float speed = 10.0F;
    Animator anim;

    void Update()
    {
        float translation = Input.GetAxis("Vertical") * speed;
        translation *= Time.deltaTime;
        transform.Translate(0, 0, translation);

        Animating(translation);
    }

    void Animating(float v)
    {
        bool roll = v != 0f;
        anim.SetBool("Roll", roll);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've updated the project and put it back up on dropbox

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/9274763/MechanimTester%20v2.zip

I added a new emtpy gameobject and made the blender cube a child of that.

The TestScript is now attached to that new gameobject and controls its position.
The animation now only applies to the child object and so the animation is no longer
interfering with the position of cube.

(What was happening was that the animation was modifying the transform for the gameobject - now as its a child its not affecting its parent so it doesn't reset the position of the overall gameobject

Does that make sense ?
    Garrett